# How to insert rows of information into different rows in a mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert

I don't know how to insert a list of info into a mysql database.

I'm trying to insert rows data into a database but it is simply inserting the last row three times.  The list is named "t" and it is a tuple .

Data:

```
11/04/19,17:33,33.4,55
11/04/19,17:34,22.9,57
11/04/19,17:35,11.9,81
```

Code:

```
import mysql.connector

sql = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='    ',
    user='    ',
    password='    ',
    db="     "
    )
cursor = sql.cursor()

f = open("C:\Cumulus\data\Apr19log.txt","r")

while True:
    s = f.readline()
    list=[]
    if (s != ""):
        t=s.split(',')
        for item in t:
            list.append(item)
    else:
        break;


sqllist =    """INSERT INTO station_fenelon (variable, date,             
time,outside_temp, outside_humidity)  
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

record =[(1, t[0], t[1], t[2],t[3]),
         (2, t[0], t[1], t[2],t[3]),
         (3, t[0], t[1], t[2],t[3])]

cursor.executemany(sqllist, record)
sql.commit()
```

I want to create three rows in the database with this list of information but is is only showing the last row of information in the database.

Comment: @Sukumar Rdjf    print (t) gives                                                                         
11/04/19,17:33,33.4,55

11/04/19,17:34,22.9,57

11/04/19,17:35,11.9,81

Comment: @Sukumar Rdjf It is a tuple

Comment: @Sukumar Rdjf 1, 2 and 3 are just auto increments in my database table so that I know where the info is going.

Comment: @Sukumar Rdjf  instead of inserting the 3 rows of information it simply inserts 11/04/19,17:35,11.9,81 three times (I made a mistake it's not twice, it's three times)

Comment: I would upvote 10 times if i could but I'm new to this and i do not have permission yet to vote on anything.

Comment: As soon as my "reputation" goes up enough i will upvote

Comment: @Sukumar Rdjf Done

Comment: @Sukumar Rdjf I wonder if you could help me with another small problem?  The problem that the format of the date in my folder is "dd/mm/yy", but in my database it is "yy/mm/dd".  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import mysql.connector
sql = mysql.connector.connect(host='',user='',password='',db='')
cursor = sql.cursor()
f = open("C:\Cumulus\data\Apr19log.txt","r")
st=[i.strip().split(',') for i in f.readlines()]

sqllist = """INSERT INTO station_fenelon (variable, date, time, outside_temp, outside_humidity) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

record = [(i+1, j[0], j[1], j[2], j[3]) for i, j in enumerate(st)]

cursor.executemany(sqllist, record)
sql.commit()
```